# Type mismatch on association, f.select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem in my form, i want to create an entry in my "members" table, each member are connected to a "year" but I keep getting mismatches on the selection of the year.

This is my form:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_area :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :nickname %><br>
<%= f.text_area :nickname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select(@years.all.map{|y| [y.year,y.id]}) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

And here are the models:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :year
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

class Year < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When I try to submit I get the following error:

Year(#70050157849460) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#9412380)

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the code for the controller

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @members = Member.all
  end
  def new
    @member = Member.new
    @years = Year.all
  end
  def create
    @member = Member.new(member_params)
    if @member.save
      flash[:success] = "Member Created"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'form'
    end
  end

  private

  def member_params
    params.require(:member).permit(:name,:nick,:position,:image,:year)
  end

end
```

Comment: Show the full controller code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_area :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :nickname %><br>
<%= f.text_area :nickname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.select :year_id, options_for_select(@years.all.map{|y| [y.year,y.id]}) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_area :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :nickname %><br>
<%= f.text_area :nickname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select(@years.all.map{|y| [y.year,y]}) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

This second I did not check but first will work you need to say year_id because when you did map on collection you set id as parameter that is being passed
but on form select you  basically told form to expect active record object.